# Doctrine: Update using collection

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

### The Problem/How

1. Pass angularJS the array result of a query that includes many joins.
2. Using angularJS to sort with ui-sortable reorders the dataset when sorting.
3. Pass data back to PHP and use synchronizeWithArray to save back (creates a collection).
4. Doctrine doesn't like receiving the data of the collection back in a different order than it outputs.
5. ** If all I change are values - without reordering elements it saves with no problems.

*Update: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-346

Noticed it was an old bug they never fixed, is there anything to still do what I want?*

### Details

```
$model = Doctrine_Core::getTable('TableName')->findOneById(...);
$model->synchronizeWithArray(array);
$model->save();
```

Doctrine (1.2) / mysql throws an Integrity error, duplicate primary key id = 2 - it is trying to change the id field.

When I reorder the elements with ui-sortable, it moves the arrays within 'Fields' around while also updating the 'position' value.

This is example data:
The problem would be array 0 and array 1 swap places - causing doctrine to cause primary key error as it tries to change the ids over.

```
array( // the root of the array is part of one table
    id => 1001,
    label => 'xxx',
    Fields => array( // related table data
        0 => array(
            id => 1,
            position => 0,
            name => 'item1'
        ),
        1 => array(
            id => 2,
            position => 1,
            name => 'item2'
        ),
        2 => array(
            id => 3,
            position => 2,
            name => 'item3'
        ),
        3 => array(
            id => 4,
            position => 3,
            name => 'item4'
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Did you test the patch on the ticket? I'm pretty sure Doctrine 1.2 is dead now, so theres need to not fork/patch it for your project. Assuming the patch works properly. But that would be my first attempt.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to access the patch from that site :S most of the site crashes for me

Comment: Ahhh.. i didnt notice it was a link to the old Trac which is probably not alive anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess we could either look on the Doctrine side and try to fix this bug, or make it work with the way Doctrine operates. The second option is probably easier.

Why don't you just save the order of the data, and put it back in that order before feeding it back to doctrine? One way to do that would be in angular. Where ever you get the array of data in angular, call saveOrder(), and before feeding it back, call reOrder():

```
var order = {};
function saveOrder(data)
{
    for(var key in data)
    {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            order[data[key].id] = key;
        }
    }
}
function reOrder(data)
{
    var ordered = [];
    for(var key in data)
    {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            ordered[order[data[key].id]] = data[key];
        }
    }
    return ordered;
}
```